# GM speaking for player

Tags: dungeon-world

I just bought the Dungeon World rulebook and am reading through it and so far really  like what I'm seeing.   I've also been watching bits and pieces of [these sessions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooa-apRt2wk&list=PL-oTJHKXHicRNYOc9unj3D1GMzjz_i6V2) on youtube.

In the gameplay videos I've noticed the GM will do things that seem to be speaking for the player.   For example  while talking to a player he will say something like:

"The winged creature flies down from the tree and starts biting and scratching at you.   You (the character) take your hand and reach up and start trying to pull the creature off of you while also trying to pull out your dagger to stab it".

(I can't remember the exact scene so this is a *completely* made up scenario but gets the point of what it sounded like he was doing during the game)

Why/when would the GM say what the character is doing at the level of detail where it sounds like he's making a move for the player?  Wouldn't/Shouldn't he just say "The creature flies down and starts biting and scratching at you.  What do you do?"

I admit I haven't read the entire GM section yet so this may be a bit premature.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not here to read the book to you; read the GMing section, and *then* if you still have questions you can edit this question with those questions, and then re-open this.

Comment: There are circumstances where narrating a PC's actions becomes the GM's job, but I can't tell from what's written here whether the example is one of those circumstances or not.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm ok with closing it

Comment: @KRyan To be fair, this is non-intuitive even after reading the GM section, especially coming from games with a firewall between GMs and PC actions. But! to be doubly fair, any answers wouldn't make sense without having read the GM section.

Comment: @earthtrip I have a suspicion that this premature question indicates you've made a common but incorrect assumption, so let me take a second to give you the most important new-GM Dungeon World advice: the GM section isn't just watery advice (like in most RPGs), it's 90% of the game rules that make DW work. Make sure you read it that way when you eventually do. :)

Comment: @earthtrip I dont think this is you reading the book wrong, I think its just that GMs style to over-narrate. Your instinct that the GM should advocating player choice and agency is correct

Comment: See also http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55865/pros-and-cons-of-2nd-person-narration